Retrieving the scroll position when the component is removed
In svelte 5, I want to store window.scrollY before the component unmounts to be able to restore it later.
I tried console logging window.scrollY inside onDestroy, the cleanup functions of onMount and $effect(), all of them just gave 0. In React's useLayoutEffect cleanup function you get the correct window.scrollY.
Is there any similar alternative to useLayoutEffect cleanup function in Svelte 5?
I know than we can solve this using event listeners but I just want to do it with effects.

Try combining the cleanup function of onMount, plus the Previous utility from @svecosystem/runed, plus the reactive svelte/reactivity/window module.  Continually save the previous scroll position until the new one becomes zero.  See how that goes.
